# Calculating the probability of $x$ number of successes in $n$ trials where each success reduces the probability of success

Tags: probability, combinatorics

E. g., there are $10$ red balls in a bag of $100$ balls, and each trial involves picking a ball out of the bag. If I get a red one, I keep it. If I do not get a red one, I place it back into the bag. I want to be able to calculate the probability that in $n$ trials I will pick $x$ red balls.

What if I keep the ball regardless of a success, and do not place any balls back into the bag. How would that change the method of calculating the probability?

Comment: If you only kept taking the balls without returning those which aren't red, I think your problem would boil down to: $\frac{\binom{10}{x}}{100\cdot 99\cdots(100-x+1)}$, but don't take my word.

Comment: Are you familiar with Markov chains?  These can be used to compute the chances of success in fairly general models of probability.

Comment: Hint for the first case (no replacement): It doesn't matter if you draw the $n$ balls one at a time or all at once.  So what is the probability that a random sample of $n$ balls, drawn without replacement, will contain exactly $x$ red balls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second question is much easier. Number the balls $1$ to $100$, so balls $1$ to $10$ are red. If you never replace any balls, then your probability space consists of all sequences of $n$ numbers, each between $1$ and $100$, with no repeats. The number of such sequences is $100\cdot 99\cdots (100-n+1)=\frac{100!}{(100-n)!}$. A successful sequences consists of $x$ red balls and $n-x$ other balls in some order. The number of successful sequences is $\binom{10}x\cdot \binom{90}{n-x}\cdot n!$ (choose $x$ red balls, choose $n-x$ non-red balls, then order them). Therefore, the probability of success is
$$
\frac{\binom{10}x\cdot \binom{90}{n-x}\cdot n!}{\frac{100!}{(100-n)!}}=\frac{\binom{10}x\cdot \binom{90}{n-x}}{\binom{100}{10}}
$$
This is the hypergeometric distribution.

---

When you have "partial replacement," so red balls are kept and non-reds are returned, then there is no simple formula. Imagine that instead of stopping after $n$ draws, you continue until all red balls are drawn. Let $T_1$ be number of draws to get your first red ball, let $T_2$ be the number of draws it takes to get your second, and so on up to $T_{10}$. Then $T_k$ is a geometric random variable for each $k$, with probability of success $(10-(k-1))/(100-(k-1))$. That is,
$$
P(T_k=m) = (1-p_k)^{m-1}p_k,\qquad \text{where }p_k=\frac{11-k}{101-k}
$$
You want to find the probability that after $n$ draws, you have exactly $x$ red balls. In order for this to occur, you need to have drawn your $x^{th}$ red ball before drawn number $n$, which means that $T_1+\dots+T_x\le n$. However, you also need to not have drawn any more red balls before draw $n$, which is equivalent to saying $T_1+\dots +T_x+T_{x+1}> n$. In order words, we want to compute
$$
P(T_1+\dots+T_x\le n)-P(T_1+\dots+T_x+T_{x+1}\le n)
$$
A good tool for computing independent sums of discrete random variables is probability generating functions. The probability generating function for a geometric distribution $Z$ with probability of success $p$ is 
$$
G_{Z}(s):=\sum_{i\ge 0}P(Z=i)s^i=\frac{sp}{1-(1-p)s}
$$
Furthermore, the p.g.f. for the sum of random variables is the product of their p.g.f's. Finally, we can recover the cumulative density function from a random variable  $Z$ by extracting the coefficient of $x^i$ in $\frac{G_Z(s)}{1-s}$. That is,
$$
P(Z\le i)=\text{coefficient of $s^i$ in } \frac{G_Z(s)}{1-s}
$$
Putting this altogether, we get

\begin{align}
P(\text{$x$ red balls in $n$ draws}) 
= \text{coefficient of $s^n$ in }\frac1{1-s}\left(\prod_{k=1}^x\frac{p_ks}{1-(1-p_k)s}\right)\left(1-\frac{p_{x+1}s}{1-(1-p_{x+1})s}\right)
=\text{coefficient of $s^n$ in }\frac1{1-(1-p_{x+1})s}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{x}\frac{p_ks}{1-(1-p_k)s}\right)
\end{align}
This is difficult to evaluate by hand, but can be done easily with a computer if $x$ and $n$ are small enough. The following Mathematica code does this:

```
p[k_] := (10-(k-1))/(100-(k-1));
G[k_] := p[k]s/(1-(1-p[k])s);
Prob[n_,x_] := SeriesCoefficient[Product[G[k],{k,1,x}]/(1-(1-p[x+1])s),{s,0,n}];
```